# Showing Jenkins pipeline status against pull requests in GitHub

Tags: github, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have recently started using Jenkins Pipelines and have a multibranch job configured which is happily picking up Jenkinsfile on one of my branches.

I have seen in screenshots on posts\articles that Jenkins can report back to pull requests in GitHub the status of whether the branch has passed\failed checks performed in the pipeline.

I am not seeing any such feedback for my pull request I have opened, I can see in Jenkins it has triggered a pipeline build which has passed.

How can I get the notification to show the pipeline checks have passed in GitHub. Do I need to configure something else?

Answer (score 0):

I found out this was simply down to me using the Git instead of GitHub sources option when configuring the multibranch pipeline job in Jenkins.

The docs for the [GitHub Branch Source](https://plugins.jenkins.io/github-branch-source) plugin gave me the clues!

I now get status messages on my pull requests showing whether pipeline checks are pending\failed\passed.

Answer (score -1):

Check out the Github Pull Request Builder Plugin, it should do what you require: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+pull+request+builder+plugin

Comment: PR Builder plugin doen't work correctly with pipelines.